# How unsecure is an 'old' wifi-router really (and what to do about it)?

Tags: router, security, firmware

My question has three parts:

1. How unsecure is a WiFi-router really, once it reaches the age where official firmware updates are no longer provided? I'm mainly considering the risk of some hacker WAN-side reaching the relatively unsecure devices on our LAN.
2. Same question as 1. - but having disabled all services on the router accessible from the internet, i.e. Remote admin, SSH, AiCloud server etc.
3. Same question as 1. - but having installed DD-WRT on the router instead of the official firmware?

Comment: That probably depends on whether an exploit is found for your particular model (or not). That you can't find one publicly does not necessarily mean there is none, by the way. Which model are we talking about exactly?

Comment: Right, so I'm asking how big is the risk of an exploit found in a router after (say) 5 years without patches? And to what degree would 2. or 3. (above) limit the risk?

Comment: We're using an Asus RT-N66U and a Linksys WRT-54, but I'm asking in general.

Comment: If you want statistics and odds I'd wait for someone else, but generally I really wouldn't connect old stuff directly to the web, this definitely includes routers. Keep in mind that even if right now it would be safe, whenever a vulnerability is found it can instantly be deployed across the internet, and we really do live in an age where this happens continuously (hence large botnets). If your local devices are not as secure, they could subsequently also be compromised without your knowing, and financial stuff, private photos, security and baby cam footage etc can end up in the wrong hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In laymen's terms there are two possible attack vectors for "old" WiFi/Routers:

1. an exploit for the router's firmware/hardware ([here's an example](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=16&product_id=19&version_id=0&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=482&sha=bd51a01b646bad788bdc715f12e17fa177698ba8))
2. a general deficiency in the algorithms e.g. for encryption (e.g. [WEP](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/wep-encryption/))

For the first attack it's important the router is still maintained and security updates are distributed on a timely basis.

The second attack vector can be avoided by switching to a secure protocol.

So eventually it doesn't matter how old a router is, as long as the router is still maintained and gives you the option to use a secure protocol.

If you use a router that isn't maintained any more, exploits won't be published any more. It doesn't matter any more which services you turn off, there is always the possibility that one of the remaining services has a vulnerability. You can reduce the risk by using open source Firmware and maintain it yourself, but this is very time intensive and usually not worth to do it just for one device.

If you can't risk unauthorized access don't use outdated routers! Otherwise you will have to make a risk assessment before hand, but it will be to complicated to do this here on superuser for you. You will need to consult an expert directly.

Comment: In "... a router that isn't maintained any more, exploits won't be published any more." did you mean "... won't be patched any more" ?

Comment: @user212498 
Actually I ment that there won't even be any more notifications about new exploits. The "patches" would be included in the "maintenance". The wording might be a little confusing, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Most consumer routers are never all that secure to begin with, even when they're brand new. It's not uncommon for the factory firmware on a new off-the-shelf router to be based on a Linux kernel or distro that's many years old and full of old vulnerabilities. Often the company (or the no-name foreign OEM/ODM that they buy their designs from) forked an old distro for internal development once upon a time, and has stuck with that same version ever since, never bothering to update the kernel or any other subsystem to the latest open source version with the latest security patches, unless they specifically got called out for still having some old vulnerability that's been long since patched in all the up-to-date distros.

When you go with an aftermarket Linux router firmware distro, at least you can see what you're getting, and you could potentially look up all the CVEs for all the open source components used in that release of that distro, but you could end up sinking a lot of time into that.

Ultimately, if you want to feel good about your network's security without becoming a Linux router security expert yourself, you should go with a product from a company that stakes its reputation on security.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at a general answer:

Even "new" stuff may have vulnerabilities.

I'd say that the age of the firmware is one factor, an update is a must as it appears.

Another factor is the firmware content and which portions of the functions you actually have active - and whether those are externally "visible" (i.e. reachable from the outside).

A more complex firmware, the more (enabled!) functions there are in it; the higher the risk.

Generally: DD-WRT might both be safer, and more vulnerable - very much dependent on the content, compared to the actually incorporated code.

I can imagine one might get some insights by googling MTBF / MTTF calculations...